# CSS @media-queries переключается на предыдущий при изменении высоты

Tags: css3, media-queries, экран

Здравствуйте! В первый раз с таким столкнулся. 
Суть вопроса. Заданы media запросы вида:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px)
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)
```

т.е. если < 480 или < 600 то css должен следовать этим правилам. НО, происходит что то странное в мобильных. Имеется чат. И input="text" где можно ввести сообщение. когда через мобильный телефон выбираете input (для ввода сообщения), на экране мобильного телефона появляется клавиатура, соответственно высота браузера уменьшается..

И когда высота браузера меньше ширины, то пропадает текущий media запрос.
пробовал добавить к запросу:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-height: 0px)
```

Не помогло.

**Обновление**

Уже интереснее. Создал снипет. https://codepen.io/volks/full/dXPLEK/
Сделал несколько media. Зашел с мобилки и ничего. Все нормально. Все корректно и высота окна не меняется.

```css
.wrap{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #222
}
.chat_area{
  background-color: #eee ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.chat_area p{
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.chat_input input{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
.chat_input span{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.other_cont{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .chat_area {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
@media only screen  and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape){
  .chat_area {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .chat_area {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .chat_area {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="chat_area">
    <p>here some chat</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chat_input">
    <input type="text" />
    <span>Send</span>
  </div>
  <div class="other_cont">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid assumenda possimus sequi amet iusto voluptates eligendi magni veritatis harum cumque, quam perferendis sapiente eum ipsa fuga alias magnam unde cum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему код в комментариях? И вообще, добавь воспроизводимый пример в сниппет в вопрос.

Comment: Первый раз задавал вопрос тут, потому так пытался выделить код. Извините. На самом деле на сайте кончено нет комментов. Снипет добавить не могу, очень много HTML и css

Comment: Ну так [mcve]...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это css, а не js. И хватит мучить кнопку автоформатирования.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, и вообще, в чём смысл добавления этого кода в вопрос, если проблема в нём не воспроизводится?

Comment: @Qwertiy Цель – обучение новых участников правилам оформления вопросов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, "Помогите мне решить проблему, которую я НЕ могу воспроизвести вот таким способом" - прям эталонный вопрос)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена. Спасибо Qwertiy!
 Все-таки пример работает, я не доглядел.. Для теста нужно (на примере Google Chrome) перейти в режим разработчика, выбрать режим мобильного просмотра и уменьшать высоту. И вы увидите, что цвет окна чата изменится.

Итак в чем была проблема. 
Когда **height** больше **width** - включается режим **media - landscape**.. и в тот момент, когда нажимаете ЧЕРЕЗ мобильный на input снизу экрана мобильного телефона вылазит клавиатура, что и делало высоту экрана меньше ширины. А так как я задал для режима **media landscape** только максимальный breakpoint (в примере max-width: 600px), то подключались стили landscape, а стили ниже по коду перебивались.. Ограничив минимальный width. Проблема была решeна.
Еще раз спасибо Qwertiy!